# CLGeocoder returns different result than MKReverseGeocoder

Tags: mkreversegeocoder, clgeocoder

I am attempting to modify our app from using `MKReverseGeocoder` to `CLGeocoder` for devices running iOS 5, but I'm getting different results from the two classes.  Specifically, when doing a reverse geocode with this coordinate:

```
(47.643126, -122.204037)
```

I get this from `MKReverseGeocoder`:

```
10210 NE Points Dr
Kirkland, Washington 98033
```

but I get this from `CLGeocoder`:

```
9601-10267 NE Points Dr
Kirkland, Washington 98033
```

The second value is much less specific than the first and therefore much less useful.  The solution for now is to just use `MKReverseGeocoder`, but at some point we'll be forced to switch.

Q: Any idea how to improve the results from `CLGeocoder`?

Thanks,
***David***

Answer (score 0):

update their database. In short their data is less specific/accurate so there is nothing you can do apart from accept their less accurate data

Comment: Yeah, I figured that.  We'll have to deal with this at some point.  Thanks for the response.